# How organize pagination with a large number of pages in Django project?

Tags: html, python-3.x, django, django-views, django-templates

I have a **view.py** product_list:

```
...
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import ProductCategory, Product, ProductDetail, ProductSpecialCategory
from django.core.paginator import Paginator, EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger
...
def product_list(request, category_slug=None, ):
category = None
categories = ProductCategory.objects.all()
object_list = Product.objects.filter(available=True, is_active=True)
if category_slug:
    category = get_object_or_404(ProductCategory, slug=category_slug)
    object_list = object_list.filter(category=category)
paginator = Paginator(object_list, 1)
page = request.GET.get('page')
try:
    products = paginator.page(page)
except PageNotAnInteger:
    products = paginator.page(1)
except EmptyPage:
    products = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
return render(request, 'shop/products/list_by_category/product_list.html', {'category': category,
                                                                            'categories': categories,
                                                                            'products': products,
                                                                            })
```

Based on this handler, I did **pagination.html**:

```
<nav aria-label="pagination" class="pagination_area">
<ul class="pagination">
    {% if page.has_previous %}
        <li class="page-item next">
            <a class="page-link" href="?page={{ page.previous_page_number }}">
                <i class="fa fa-angle-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </a>
        </li>
    {% endif %}
    {% for i in page.paginator.page_range %}
        {% if page.number == i %}
            <li class="page-item focused"><a class="page-link" href="?page={{ i }}">{{ i }}</a></li>
            {% elif i > page.number|add:'-1' and i < page.number|add:'1' %}
            {% else %}
            <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?page={{ i }}">{{ i }}</a></li>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    {% if page.has_next %}
        <li class="page-item next">
            <a class="page-link" href="?page={{ page.next_page_number }}">
                <i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </a>
        </li>
    {% endif %}
</ul>
```

On the interface, I get the **result**:

[image]

I would like to organize in such a way that:

*Show only three pages, the first of which is the previous one, the second is the current, the third is the next. And what is not included in this range are hidden by ellipses, for example.*:

[image: Expected Result]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I change **pagination.html**. Please try this.

```
<nav aria-label="pagination" class="pagination_area">
<div class="row">
  {% if page.end_index > 0 %}
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-5 d-none d-md-block">
    <p>Showing {{ page.start_index }} to {{ page.end_index }} of {{ page.paginator.count}}.</p>
  </div>
  {% endif %}
  {% if page.paginator.num_pages > 1 %}
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-7 dataTables_pager">
    <ul class="pagination">
      {% if page.has_previous %}

        <li class="page-item">
          <a class="page-link" data-page="1" href="?page={{ page.previous_page_number }}">
            <i class="fa fa-angle-double-left"></i>
          </a>
        </li>
        {% if page.previous_page_number > 1 %}
          <li class="page-item">
            <a class="page-link " data-page="{{page.previous_page_number}}"  href="?page={{ page.previous_page_number }}">
              <i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>
            </a>
          </li>
        {% endif %}

      {% endif %}

      {% if page.previous_page_number > 2 %}
        <li class="page-item">
          <a class="page-link " data-page="{{page.number|add:'-2'}}" href="?{{page.number|add:'-2'}}"> {{ page.number|add:"-2" }} </a>
         </li>
        <li class="page-item">
          <a class="page-link " data-page="{{page.number|add:'-1'}}" href="?page={{page.number|add:'-1'}}"> {{ page.number|add:"-1" }} </a>
        </li>
      {% endif %}

      <li class="page-item active"><span class="page-link ">{{ page.number }}</span></li>

      {% if page.paginator.num_pages > page.number|add:"2" %}
        <li class="page-item">
          <a class="page-link " data-page="{{page.number|add:'1'}}" href="?page={{page.number|add:'1'}}"> {{ page.number|add:"1" }} </a>
        </li>
        <li class="page-item">
          <a class="page-link " data-page="{{page.number|add:'2'}}" href="?page={{page.number|add:'2'}}"> {{ page.number|add:"2" }} </a>
        </li>
      {% endif %}

      {% if page.has_next %}
        <li class="page-item">
          <a class="page-link " data-page="{{page.next_page_number}}" href="?page={{ page.next_page_number }}">
            <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
          </a>
        </li>

        <li class="page-item">
          <a class="page-link " data-page="{{page.paginator.num_pages}}" href="?page={{page.paginator.num_pages}}">
            <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i>
          </a>
        </li>
      {% endif %}
    </ul>
  </div>
  {% endif %}
</div>
</nav>
```

My design just like this. If you change design for your needs.
Here click `<<` to go first page , `>>` to go last page , `<` to go previous page and `>` to go next page.

[image]

Comment: I agree, I tried it and everything is fine! Thanks, now I understand this logic at the display level in templates!